# Django: make_password outputs different password than django.auth

Tags: python, django, passwords, password-encryption

I am trying to implement a user password history, so that the user can not use the same passwords twice when updating his password.
I am using the Django auth module for this.

To achieve that I just save the new passwords the user creates in an additional sql table `my_userpasswordhistory`.

After that, I created a new PasswordValidator to check the new password against the old passwords. 
They way I intend to do that, is to take all old passwords from the user in the database, split off the `salt` and run `make_password(newpassword, salt)`.

See the following code:

```
    pass_list = UserPasswordHistory.objects.all().filter(user=user)

    for old_pass in pass_list:
        #split password so we get the hash and the salt
        split_pass = old_pass.password.split('$')
        salt = split_pass[2]
        pw   = split_pass[-1]
        if make_password(password, salt) == old_pass.password:
            raise ValidationError(
                _('Your new Password needs to be different from your old one!'),
                code='password_identic'
            )
```

**Problem**

The problem I am having is that somehow, the password generated by Django in the admin backend (via interface) is different from the password I create with using `make_password()`.

The value in the database for my password is:

`select password from my_userpasswordhistory;`
`pbkdf2_sha256$36000$trlHVdErn23Z$BAxX9p3o54QGovIWluP3dM7q73HQNZy9VuYOA6rv268=`

However, using the salt `trlHVdErn23Z` on the an identic raw password, I get:

`pbkdf2_sha256$36000$trlHVdErn23Z$6WbA/0fUvDi82GjN7lqjdMoaDiaoojGY3A913CGuFBY=`

Also, running `make_password()` multiple times will always output the same (second) password hash.

I can not figure out if Django uses some additional randomizer whilst creating the password in the admin panel, if I found a bug, or more likely, I missed something.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I am a little concerned about `make_password`, it iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Note: NIST currently suggests not to expire passwords password. That was an old idea for an old way we used computers. Today, don't make people change their passwords unless there's indication of compromise. See: [NIST Digital Identity Guidelines](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf)

Comment: I agree with the NIST succestion, but the client requires this feature. As this is "feature" is only accessible after login or after losing the password, I don't see how it can be related to brute force. (If the attacker logged in, its already too late, adding security to this script won't do anything)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `check_password` instead of `make_password`.

From the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password)

> **check_password(password, encoded)**
>
> If you’d like to manually authenticate a user by comparing a plain-text password to the hashed password in the database, use the convenience function check_password(). It takes two arguments: the plain-text password to check, and the full value of a user’s password field in the database to check against, and returns True if they match, False otherwise.

Comment: That won't work, because the hash is different for all past passwords.

If it were only one password, the method you are proposing would work, but I need to be able to verify the new password against a range of old passwords.